# Parent object is null when getting child objects using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
public class AcsBatchingDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CardHolder> CardHolders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccessCard> AccessCards { get; set; }
}

public class CardHolder
{
    public int CardHolderId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AccessCard> AccessCards { get; set; };
}


public class AccessCard
{

    public int AccessCardId { get; set; }
    public CardHolder CardHolder { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to get AccessCards

```
using (var db = new AcsBatchingDbContext())
{
    var cards = db.AccessCards.ToList();
}
```

Where card.CardHolder = null

**Why? Why EF doesnt grab the CardHolder?**

Another question:

**Why this expression doesnt compile?**

```
db.AccessCards.Include(x => x.CardHolder).ToList();
```

Why the only options is to use is

```
db.AccessCards.Include("CardHolder").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use include to load `CardHolder` entity.

(This requires `using System.Data.Entity;`)

```
db.AccessCards.Include(x => x.CardHolder).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can apply `Include` like this;

```
db.AccessCards.Include("CardHolder").ToList();
```

Comment: For some reason this "Include" signature is not available,  instead this one worked: db.AccessCards.Include("CardHolder").ToList(); only with a string param. Dont understand why :(